# how to recall def function using juypter notebook

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, typeerror

I want to apply sentiment analysis using juypter notebook,
this is my code

pos_list = positive_words['Positive'].values.tolist()

def pos_sentiment(tweet):
count=0
for word in pos_list:
if word in tweet:
count+=1
return count

clean_data['pos_count'] = clean_data['tweetText'].apply(lambda x: pos_sentiment(x))

this error occur

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 clean_data['pos_count'] = clean_data['tweetText'].apply(lambda x: pos_sentiment(x))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
4198             else:
4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
4201
4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

in (x)
----> 1 clean_data['pos_count'] = clean_data['tweetText'].apply(lambda x: pos_sentiment(x))

in pos_sentiment(tweet)
2     count=0
3     for word in pos_list:
----> 4         if word in tweet:
5             count+=1
6     return count

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a float in this line

```
clean_data['pos_count'] = clean_data['tweetText'].apply(lambda x: pos_sentiment(x))
```

Because if you go inside the function pos_sentiment(x) it should take a list not a float

What you should do is :

```
clean_data['pos_count'] = pd.Series(pos_sentiment(clean_data['tweetText'].tolist()))
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammed for respond, but there is no output related to the function